# Why form hide when I click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `div` which show when I click on link. I wrote some js, if I click beyond the borders of this `div`, it must hide. But I faced with such problem, if I click for example on input with id `fullFilter`, it hide.

I wrote this to resolve this issue

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.class != 'full-filter' && e.target.id != 'fullFilter' && e.target.id != 'resetFilter' && e.target.id != 'salaryFrom' && e.target.id != 'salaryTo') {
        $('.full-filter').hide();
    }
});
```

But if I click on my form, it also hide. It class is `full-filter`. What I do wrong? Please, help

Comment: Try `e.target.className` instead of `e.target.class`

Comment: `$('.full-filter').hide();` <-- I'm *fairly certain* that's why a form with the class `full-filter` is being hidden...

Comment: `console.log(e.target)` I doubt it is the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to walk the tree to find if you are clicking inside the form. The easiest way of doing it is using `closest`.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ( !$(e.target.closest(".full-filter").length) {
        $('.full-filter').hide();
    }
});
```